# Comparators that can drive large capacitive loads

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, comparator, mixed-signal

I quote from Allen and Holberg, 3e, Pg 468:

> If a comparator has a large capacitive load, the chances are that it is slew rate limited. Under these conditions, we will show several methods capable of driving large values of CII. The first method is simply to add several push-pull inverters in cascade with the output of a two-stage, open-loop comparator.

> It can be shown that if the W/L increases by a factor of 2.72, the minimum propagation delay time is achieved.

How is this value 2.72 arrived at? Is this number technology node dependent?

[image: Comparator Image added for Reference]

Comment: I'm thinking there are several more parameters and values involved in the problem statement.

Comment: What is the RdsOn*Cout for this  ratio and gm/Id? Can you link reference?

Comment: Page "VII.6-1" [here](https://xdevs.com/doc/_Books/ASIC_Design/%28ebook%29%20cmos%20analog%20circuit%20design%20%28allen-holberg%29.pdf) or [here](https://studylib.net/doc/18290886/section-7---comparators) gives a clue as to what they are getting at.